# Mapping an address to two balances

Tags: solidity, tokens, addresses, mapping, balances

I want to map an address to two balances, because in contract, we have two types of token i.e. energy and power. Is following code is correct in solidity program ?

```
mapping(address => uint256) Enbalances;
mapping(address => uint256) Pwbalances;
```

Here is function to get balance of energy :

```
function balanceOfEn(address _owner) constant returns (uint256 Enbalance) {
    return Enbalances[_owner];
  }
```

and I call this function as follows :

```
contractInstance.methods.balanceOfEn('0x1c3bcab2050Fbe3A0c4958dd5776558EE9720460').call({ from: '0x1c3bcab2050Fbe3A0c4958dd5776558EE9720460' }, function(error, result) {
    console.log(error);
    console.log(result)
});
```

P.S. when I want to get a balance, I receive the following error:

```
> Error: Couldn't decode uint256 from ABI: 0x
    at SolidityTypeUInt.formatOutputUInt (/home/ubuntu/parityewf/node_modules/we                                                                                                             b3-eth-abi/src/formatters.js:174:15)
    at SolidityTypeUInt.SolidityType.decode (/home/ubuntu/parityewf/node_modules                                                                                                             /web3-eth-abi/src/type.js:252:17)
    at /home/ubuntu/parityewf/node_modules/web3-eth-abi/src/index.js:327:49
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at ABICoder.decodeParameters (/home/ubuntu/parityewf/node_modules/web3-eth-a                                                                                                             bi/src/index.js:326:13)
    at Contract._decodeMethodReturn (/home/ubuntu/parityewf/node_modules/web3-et                                                                                                             h-contract/src/index.js:459:22)
    at Method.outputFormatter (/home/ubuntu/parityewf/node_modules/web3-eth-cont                                                                                                             ract/src/index.js:812:46)
    at Method.formatOutput (/home/ubuntu/parityewf/node_modules/web3-core-method                                                                                                             /src/index.js:163:54)
    at sendTxCallback (/home/ubuntu/parityewf/node_modules/web3-core-method/src/                                                                                                             index.js:467:33)
    at /home/ubuntu/parityewf/node_modules/web3-core-requestmanager/src/index.js                                                                                                             :147:9
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/home/ubuntu/parityewf/node_mo                                                                                                             dules/web3-providers-http/src/index.js:77:13)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/home/ubuntu/parityewf/node_modu                                                                                                             les/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:64:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/home/ubuntu/parityewf/node_modules/xhr2/l                                                                                                             ib/xhr2.js:354:12)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/home/ubuntu/parityewf/node_modules/xh                                                                                                             r2/lib/xhr2.js:509:12)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/parityewf/node_modules/xhr2/lib                                                                                                             /xhr2.js:469:24)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)
```

Is following alternative code for mapping address to two balances is correct?

```
mapping (address => uint256) Enbalances;
mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) Pwbalances;
```

Comment: what error do you receive?

Comment: it looks like it's related to your js code, and not ETH. Plus, if you set your two mappins as public, Solidity will create automatic getters so you don't have to.

Comment: https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1089

Comment: It seems you have the wrong ABI for this contract, maybe an outdated version of your contract?

Comment: @Eli Drion What is you opinion about 
mapping (address => uint256) Enbalances; mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) Pwbalances;
? it is not better ?

Comment: I think it's unnecessary in your case.

Comment: @ Eli Drion Do you think if I replace it with mapping(address => uint256) Enbalances;
mapping(address => uint256) Pwbalances; it works?

Comment: @Eli Drion I updated ABI but I have still same problem Must I deploy contract again?

Comment: It seems you are yourself lost between your different versions. Deploy one on the testnet with the "simple" mappings, update the ABI and try. It should work.

Answer (score 1):

1. Rebuild your artifacts (using `truffle compile` for example)
2. You can simplify `contractInstance.methods.balanceOfEn('...').call({ from: '...' })`

   To `contractInstance.balanceOfEn('...', { from: '...' })`

   And in fact, since `Enbalances` is declared `public`, you can get rid of function `balanceOfEn` in your contract, and then use `contractInstance.Enbalances('...', { from: '...' })`

Comment: What is you opinion about 
mapping (address => uint256) Enbalances; 
mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) Pwbalances;
? it is not better ?

Comment: My ABI is generated by remix and also I tested another function and it works. but in case of balanceOfEn I have this problem.

Comment: @goodvibrationI updated ABI but I have still same problem Must I deploy contract again?